# Сохранить форматирование при выборке из БД

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript, mysql

Имею в БД запись в таком виде:

```
Сдать деньги:

  -Студент1
  -Студент2
  -Студент3
  -Студент4

           До 12.05.2014
```

В приложение которое сделал на Android, выводит **Так же, сохраняя форматирование**.

А вот при выводе на сайте выходит шляпа...

```
Сдать деньги:-Студент1-Студент2-Студент3
-Студент4До 12.05.201
```

P.S Знаю про **htmlentities**, но это не то что нужно, ведь в Андроиде(TextView) выводит все отлично, почему не выводит нормально на сайт?

P.S.S использую через AJAX принимаю данные и вывожу на сайт в таком виде:

```
check +=  "<div id='item_image'><img src='../NImages/"+data[i].Image+"'/></div>";
check +=  "<div id='item_lower'>"+data[i].LowerText+"</div></div>";
```

**data[i].LowerText** это и есть тот самый текст.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Полагаю, что textView на аднроиде воспринимает переводы строки как это и полагается, а для html \n ни о чем не говорит, надо использовать <br>. К тому же множество пробелов подряд игнорируются, преобразовываясь в один. Как вариант, вам надо обработать строку из БД перед выводом в html, заменив:

1. переводы строки (\n, \r\n, \r) на
       <br>
2. заменить пробелы на &nbsp;

Другой вариант, выводите ваш не отформатированный текст в тэг <pre> http://jsfiddle.net/KRj8w/

Comment: Спасибо, отличный вариант.